# Place question mark submit button inside input text field

Tags: html, css

I have an input field and a submit button which looks like a question mark due to css styling. This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

How can I position the question mark inside the input field like this:

[image]

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
div h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}
div p {
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  height: 35px;
}
.submit {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Sub-Heading</p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="text">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="?">
  </form>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ea1vrume/

I have tried the following styling for the submit button, but it places it way out from where I want it to be:

```
.submit {
   position: absolute;
   top: 2px;
   right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `?` button inside the textbox:

- apply the style `position: relative` to your `<form>`
- apply the style `right: 25%` to your `?` button

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
div h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}
div p {
  text-align: center;
}
.text {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 22px;
  height: 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.submit {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 25%;
}
form {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Sub-Heading</p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="text">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="?">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to vertically center the submit button?

Comment: @TheCodesee One way to do that is to change the `top` style of the button to `12px`. Check my updated code.

Comment: Any chance we could stop the text overlapping the submit button?

Comment: @TheCodesee Checkout my updated code. I have changed the `padding-right` value of of the textbox, added `box-sizing` . Also changed the `top` value of the button. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning will pull this off. Assign `position: relative;` to the parent, and I made it `inline-block` so that it would only wrap the content inside instead of being 100% width of the page, then position the `.submit` button absolutely over the text input.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

div h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

div p {
  text-align: center;
}

.submit {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0px;
}
form {
  text-align: center;
}
form > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.submit {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.text {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Sub-Heading</p>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="username" class="text">
      <input type="submit" class="submit" value="?">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I noticed the input field is no longer centered.

Answer (score 0):

See if this help https://jsfiddle.net/ea1vrume/1/

HTML

```
<div>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Sub-Heading</p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="text">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="?">
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  text-align: center;
}

div h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

div p {
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  height: 35px;
}

.submit {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  right: 0px;
}
```